# chrome : mousewheel scroll expands textarea's height

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have an issue with resizeable textareas in chrome (version 52)

When the resize handle (located in the bottom right corner of the textarea) is hovered and scrolled, the height of the textarea is changed (scroll up = height++, scoll down = height--)

[Try to scroll while hovering the handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/590g9.png)

I need to disable this behavior while keeping the textareas resizable.

I don't see any good reason for this behavior to exists...
BTW this doesn't happen in IE/Firefox...

Comment: simple textarea fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/upLxn0b4/

Comment: the issue is still happening in chrome 53

Comment: still going on in chrome 54 :'(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed as of chrome version 56.